# When I create VIEW there is a wrong result, while simple SQL query gives a correct result

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-view

This is how I define a rule for my VIEW:

```
SELECT `yearByWeek`, `week`, ( SELECT MIN(dolphin_day.date) ) AS 'start', ( SELECT SUM(dolphin_day.countHour)) AS 'countHours'

FROM `dolphin_day`
GROUP BY `yearByWeek`, `week`
ORDER BY `yearByWeek` DESC, `week` DESC
```

❌ wrong result for VIEW is the following:

[image]

✅ correct result for SQL query:

[image]

Why result for view is totally wrong?

Comment: Do you have a problem if you define the view from the `mysql` CLI client instead of PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: I dont know how to verify what you have asked me for;) I am not professional with mysql /php. I know only the basic;)

Comment: Type `mysql` from the command line. Then enter `CREATE VIEW viewMonth AS SELECT ...` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregations shouldn't be in subqueries.

```
SELECT `yearByWeek`, `week`, MIN(date) AS 'start', SUM(countHour) AS 'countHours'
FROM `dolphin_day`
GROUP BY `yearByWeek`, `week`
ORDER BY `yearByWeek` DESC, `week` DESC
```